# Action vise versa in Admin Django

Tags: django, django-models, django-admin

i write an action for class in admin.py

```
class YarnsAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    actions = [make_stockable_unstockable]
```

i want this action to change status vise versa of stockable for the product.

my try is:

```
def make_stockable_unstockable(self, request, queryset):

    for product in queryset:
        if product.stockable:
            queryset.filter(id=product.id).update(stockable=False)
        else:
            queryset.filter(id=product.id).update(stockable=True)

    self.message_user(request, "Position(s) were updated")
```

it works, but i think this takes a lot of resources.
if anyone has an idea to optimize it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since Django 1.8, [Conditional Expressions](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/models/conditional-expressions/) (`SQL`'s `Case..When..`) are supported.

Thus the following django ORM single update statement should accomplish what you need

```
from django.db.models import Case, When, F, Q, BooleanField, Value
queryset.annotate(new_value=Case(
        When(Q(stockable=False), then=Value(True)),
        default=Value(False),
        output_field=BooleanField()
    )).update(stockable=F('new_value'))
```

it generates the following sql

```
UPDATE `yourmodel` 
    SET `stockable` = CASE WHEN `yourmodel`.`stocakble` = 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END 
    WHERE <queryset's filters>
```

for the record, here is the original, **wrong solution** I initially proposed

> you could issue just two updates instead of looping:
>
>     `queryset.filter(stockable=False).update(stockable=True)`
>     `queryset.filter(stockable=True).update(stockable=False)`
>
>  which will flip the flag with two update statements

Comment: No, this won't work. With first action you change everything that False to True. and the second action changes ALL to False

Comment: WOW. This solution works fine, thanks. But i don't find it faster. a have debug toolbar. it shows same number of queries and the same time. what do you think about it?

Comment: how big is your queryset? Also, this code should be without the loop. But in performance improvements, it's always profiling, profiling, and just because something is more elegant, it might not be faster. Another thing, dev dbs with a few rows behave differently from production dbs with ten-hundred thousands of records (even if only updating a few of them)

Comment: at the moment queryset is just 4 objects (sqlite) . applying action it takes 9 queries and about 2.30ms. You are right about looping, it always take extra resources. I will use your solution, thank you. but at first i will get into it =) i just copy/pased it without getting what's going on and it looks  complecated =)

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use the bulk update which fires single query for bunch of records instead of one query per record.

```
def make_stockable_unstockable(self, queryset):
    queryset.filter(stockable=False).update(stockable=True)
    queryset.filter(stockable=True).update(stockable=False)
```

Comment: No, this won't work. With first action you change everything that False to True. and the second action changes ALL to False